# javac:command not found, jps : command not found

Tags: linux, environment-variables

I Have machine with redhat 3.10.0. Kindly help in understanding following points

1. unable to locate javac

/usr/bin/java is linked as follows:

/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.5.5.el7.x86_64/bin/java

JAVA_HOME i set to  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.5.5.el7.x86_64/jre
this has bin and lib folders.

i added  /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.5.5.el7.x86_64/jre/bin in PATH variable
i couldnt find javac at these paths.

2. unable to locate jps
   i checked JAVA_HOME/bin path , no exe is there .

Comment: There shall not be an exe file in *nix environment.

Comment: I meant executables, where would I find them if they exist on machine.

Comment: is it only jre is installed on machine and not jdk? because /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.5.5.el7.x86_64 should have bin folder if jdk is installed which is not present .......... I tried command rpm -qa | grep java to find installed components..... this was outcome ....java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.51-2.4.5.5.el7.x86_64
python-javapackages-3.4.1-5.el7.noarch
tzdata-java-2014b-1.el7.noarch
javapackages-tools-3.4.1-5.el7.noarch
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.51-2.4.5.5.el7.x86_64